# Warning on Razor when <img width="@someVar">

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor

Having the following .cshtml :

```
@{ int someVar = 300; }
<img width="@someVar">
```

Visual Studio (2012) gives me a warning :

```
 Warning    1   '@width' is not a valid value of attribute 'width'.
```

It does work ok, but I'm wondering if there's any way to pass a variable to the width attribute without having this warning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the value in parentheses, like so:

```
@{ int someVar = 300; }
<img width="@(someVar)">
```

The warning should then disappear.

Comment: doesn't work : Warning 6 '@(someVar)' is not a valid value of attribute 'width'.

Comment: visual studios 2017, adding the `()` and then removing it fixed the issue for me. weird